# How to load images for a image in background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7

I am using a panorama page which has a Image and a text blocks.

The images for the image is loaded from web, that i have images links and the caption in a List. Now am using binding in xaml for the image and text block.

The images are getting loaded automatically but when it takes more time due to more number of parorama pages my application gets closed due to overtime of UI response time.

So i hope the images should loaded out of UI thread and in someother background thread.

Is there any possibility to load these kind of images in lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend loading the Images using David Ansons's LowProfileImageLoader. You can find more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/10/04/there-s-no-substitute-for-customer-feedback-improving-windows-phone-7-application-performance-now-a-bit-easier-with-lowprofileimageloader-and-deferredloadlistbox-updates.aspx?Redirected=true) and download a [package from nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/PhonePerformance). It is a clever library that downloads and decodes images using a background thread.

It helped me a lot with performance issues when dealing with images. It is also very easy to use.